# How to detect zip file encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption, linux, zip

As we know zip files supports a simple password-based symmetric encryption system and some vendors use other algorithms. I used the `zipinfo` command in Linux but it doesn't say what encryption algorithm is used. How can I find that out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

7Zip archiver (freeware) has an info button that among other useful things tell you the encryption type an archive is using.

As a general note, .Zips usually use something called "ZipCrypto Deflatte".

Comment: If you want to use command line, try `7z l -slt path/to/file.zip`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows in Total Commander you can press Ctrl+PageDown to enter the archive. Right click > Properties on any file will tell you the encryption type.

Comment: This is a Linux question

Comment: Please read the question more precisely and keep note of the tags used...

Comment: right, sorry about that